# Declaring that a datetime is daylight saving

Tags: .net, powershell, datetime

I'd like to declare that a datetime is daylight saving.

I am generating the `datetime` with `datetime.parseexact()`.  It appears that the `datetime.isdaylightsavingtime()` method returns `true`.

Note that I am parsing a string that specifies the time zone simply as `EDT` or `EST`.

Comment: The abbreviations `EST/EDT` aren't unique `Get-TimeZone -ListAvailable|where ID -match 'Eastern'`, might be a better idea to convert to base utc from your context.

Comment: I know this.  I can determine this via a lookup table.  But, I can't determine if `[datetime]N` is daylight saving time so that .net datetime conversion methods will function properly.  This is my question.  I truly just think that, since I have to provide a lookup table, I'll just perform the necessary adjustment back to non-daylight saving time when applicable (as in N-1 for `EDT` and N for `EST`), and then convert to UTC.  Note that I'm processing CSVs from Tenable's Nessus, and it's a shit show of proprietary stuff, may be why "EDT" and "EST" are used instead of something unique.

Comment: I don't agree with this strategy: https://community.tenable.com/s/question/0D5f200005VVbS5CAL/different-time-zone-in-securitycenter-reports

Comment: I'll take a look at this as it does seem relevant.

Comment: Oh right!  Daylight saving time has a declared timespan for which it is in place for all time zones.  Therefore, .NET determines this for historic and future dates, although government policy can change future DST time spans, the current one must be used.  Thank you for pointing that out.